# How to Use A Value Entered in Do While Loop After Exiting the Do While Loop in C

Tags: c, for-loop, do-while

I'm a newbie in C programming. I'm curious to know if it's possible to take a value entered in do while loop and use it outside the loop. Tried to code it a few times but it's not working for me. Appreciate a lot if someone could help me out in this matter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float salary, hours, bonus;
  float rateperhour = 2.50;
  do {
    printf("Please enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%f", &hours);
    salary = hours * rateperhour;
    if (salary > 500 && salary < 1000) {
      printf("Range: 5000-10000\n");
    } else {
      hours = 0;
    }
    printf("Salary: %.2f\n", salary);
  } while (hours > 0);
  for (bonus = 10; bonus <= 15; ++bonus) {
    salary = hours * bonus;
  }
  printf("Salary: %d", salary);
}
```

Comment: Your variables are declared outside the loops at the very begin and they are accessible in the whole function, you have a bug here: `printf("Salary: %d", salary);` --> `printf("Salary: %.0f", salary);`

Comment: Also, this loop doesn't make sense: `for (bonus = 10; bonus <= 15; ++bonus) salary = hours * bonus;`, you can replace it with `salary = hours * 15;`, or do you mean `salary += hours * bonus;`?

Answer (score 1):

> "*How to use a value entered in a `do while` loop after exiting the `do while` loop in C?*"

If the object the value is assigned to is declared outside the loop, there is no problem of accessing the object outside of the loop.

If the object is contrary declared inside the loop only, it has only its lifetime and scope within the loop.

But that is not the problem with your code.

---

> "*Tried to code it a few times but it's not working for me.*"

That is not the reason why it does not print the expected output. Beside the mistake of the wrong format specifier at the last `printf` call:

```
printf("Salary: %d", salary);
```

instead of

```
printf("Salary: %.0f", salary);
```

or

```
printf("Salary: %d", (int) salary);
```

because `salary` is of type `float`,

there is nothing syntactically wrong with your code as you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtaXAMylV6ADJ5amAHJ6ARpmIhjAB1TTCS2pp36jpNw9FOgsrW10HJ2NZeWDaBgJmYgIfPQNOaLlMBS8EpIJQm3tHZxlE5NS/DLL8wvDI5wBKGVRtYmQOAHIAUgAmQ0tkHSwAam7DdWkCfFQAOgRx7G6ABgBBSwIR3WZLCEaxgHYAIRXVkZGqVlRmTek2JIBPUhGEVuJpZ7s6bWlxk7XzpdrptiDdMC5HK82mNDAAREa9WYAVmWf1O53QqEO/zO5xGLmIGyoED6vQACuxmLIRqoCI4Xm9pCMAO4kADWmHQIDGvV6jTRALx0hYtGJpL6SKopOefQAbFD3vzDDi8SM7sJiA8YfCFUyAFQjUF0iHEBUC3HnPBUEYQdWPGHYEYo5Y82VytX3TUw9QjTjLf37brHdGq/GE%2Bhi3kAJREwA4Tv9ywAtH7E90kepaKSlSq8UH4XJqUHc6rddqRqjlSHzvnq2GiSTeQxPQ9uRLZr0pRms7znnbNTmQ/mWQg8OwbWXFhXB4KaMQbV9aD9y36/iNF8vxupxvDOEi130Tr0jhvpIHg4Lzv2tTuGW19evvr8q4La4KCQ3Sc2Na2eZLpR6P4zqs%2BadM0rAgJ0SKdKQBidMsMGoJBPrSG8HQ8oYnAwQQkEIY0zRsiA3DLLMsqYUiBwABwAJzcAchiypR3C8BBnTcDBuhcP6sG4YhkEwdIIDLKQOHwWBpBwLASBoLoLhjo45CUDJcnsE4yDANRxhUGOdLvJQdi8aQdiWI8kFYaQMm6LSADytCsK2YmkFg2yiOwhn4MQ2SKAAbpggmOZgAAe2TaHShkbHIhmsHgdigpqmhYGZ2GEpxnRYc0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIoggBIYhSNFdiCZAzSoC4cT%2BUmADqbCsCMjWOMQJACVkOTKBApiVOkJhqHUxROJwATuJ4dADYIgRTbQI0RCU40xF5uTlCkWhpIIq09fEG2LQ0K0bTNx21JYRRLWNzSoW0HRcOBkHQTxjlIZ0gWUbKSaytwIzAMgyAjNRsyGDauCECQGHjSMmiyfJ859Jh%2BzqNhvH4aQhG8siBycJ9KK4wcdHEcYrHsaQnGpi9CGkG9AlCSJaMSTAiAgK0BAuKFikQMp8OCJyENjaQmWMCwbl5cyoIuElj1QTBcHU29iOcCyhAICMH1fT9f0A0DIOo2J6OEZwBwdsbsrLJ9spItwZEZL0QiQWT8t8Z0dPCaJeFM/AEDSagcOqVzPOqSgQyxtR3HaawumCRABmOcZtCmWlMGWTZdkOdTzmxm5jkeWtvn%2BdTQUhWFjkRax1PlXFDwJV05kECl0tC3QIs5VwvACPbhXiJIQgxZVew07VXj%2BV1sReCoainUN5gXfUy0TUEXjT3NcSHQvu1xHkFRbVUMjdVvB1z6NO0nbvg1TOdYQn5wN1oblpDMiIBDWbVACSopvelDuy1TLsa99X6odRC6xIi6CA4MiAI36NDWGKl6SIz5DDfWeECJcGBhRGidEGJMV6H6WUP8naGVpjIemHswIy16BxLiwlnY034gzA2zRfLvAntwIAA), so you might look at the logic behind the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

What  you want to do in :

```
for (bonus = 10; bonus <= 15; ++bonus) {
   salary =hours * bonus;
  }
```

I mean how your Bonus system works ? you add a bonus to the salary ?
tell me that so I can help you

Comment: The program itself is converted from a pseudocode. As for the bonus part it goes like this FOR(bonus=10,bonus≤15,increase bonus by 1)
START FOR
salary EQUALTO hours MULTIPLY bonus
END FOR
DISPLAY salary


I'm trying to display the value of the salary without having to input a new value again.

Comment: But the for loop doesn't have a sens if you don't use a condition in your case , once you've calculated the salary in do while loop, do you want to add a bonus for this salary ? if yes tell me in a simple sentense the scale for this